# Does it need to close connection pool for Azure SQL in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I am using `mssql` package to connect to a SQL Server using `'ConnectionPool'`.

This is my code:

```
const sql = require("mssql");
const config = require("../config/config");
const dynamic_retrieve_query = require("./Query/retrieveQuery");

const pool1 = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
const pool1Connect = pool1.connect();

pool1.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

class Database {
  static async retrieveContactIdCallBack(org_name, column_name, id) {
    // ensure pool has been created
    await pool1Connect;
    console.log(pool1Connect);

    try {
      const request = pool1.request();
      const query = dynamic_retrieve_query.retrieveProgramTable(
        org_name,
        column_name,
        id
      );
      const result = await request.query(query);
      //   pool1.close();
      return result.recordset;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("SQL Error", err);
      return err;
    }
  }

  static async getContactLanguageTable(org_name, column_name, id) {
    // ensure pool has been created
    await pool1Connect;
    console.log(pool1Connect);

    try {
      const request = pool1.request();
      const query = dynamic_retrieve_query.getContactLanguageTable(
        org_name,
        column_name,
        id
      );
      const result = await request.query(query);

      return result.recordset;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("SQL Error", err);
      return err;
    }
  }
}
module.exports = Database;
```

Then, I call those class in other JS file to retrieve data without closing the connection pool. When it runs the code, the program does run successfully without the error. But, I would like to know that it does need to close the connection pool for each one request? or  Does it find without closing connection pool?

If there are many connection, there will be server overload or abort?

If it does need to close the connection, when and how to close connection pool?

Could you please explain them and suggest other reference or documentation for ConnectionPool in SQL Server?